# How to use Stored Procedures with Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I having problems at trying to call a MySQL Stored Procedure with Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine 1.2. What I want to do is the following:

In a module/new after typing all the data in the form, I want to insert one of the values in   another table.

I don't know if this can be done with Doctrine without using a stored procedure.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use triggers but I'm not sure how advanced they are in MySQL. Triggers wouldn't involve any coding in Doctrine, symfony nor PHP. Just stored procedures.

You can achieve pretty similar effect with Doctrine's [record listeners](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/event-listeners.html#record-listeners) or [record hooks](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/event-listeners.html#record-hooks).

Comment: Just did various test with the triggers. Thanks for your help Kuba.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this this using Doctrine_RawSQL Cf. [Doctrine API ref](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/native-sql)

But for your example, there seems to have no need to use stored procedures. Instead hook into controller to add others records, or, as kuba suggested use records hooks.

Comment: Thanks Benoit.I'm still a little confused with the hooks but I'll test them out.