# How to execute Stored Procedures with Doctrine2 and MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working in a Symfony2 application and I need to use Stored Procedures to do some high performance processes.

There are any way to execute (and manage parameters) a MySQL Stored Procedure using Doctrine2?

**SOLUTION:**

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$qb = $em->createNativeQuery(
        'CALL USR_P_UserRegistration (' .
            ':iduser, :name, :surname, :birthday, :idlang, :idregistry' .
        ')',
        new ResultSetMapping()
    );
$qb->setParameters(
    array(
        'iduser' => $c->getIduser(),
        'name' => $c->getName(),
        'surname' => $c->getSurname(),
        'birthday' => $c->getBirthday(),
        'idlang' => $c->getIdlang(),
        'idregistry' => $c->getIdregistry()
    ));
$qb->execute();
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use Native SQL and you could even use stored procedures for data retrieval.

[doc Native sql](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html)

or you can view this link

[How to use Stored Procedures with Symfony and Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198647/how-to-use-stored-procedures-with-symfony-and-doctrine)

Comment: I get a General Error from MySQL (details above). Maybe I am using the wrong execute method?

Comment: This is not an answer. This is just posting the links to other resources.

Answer (score -1):

```
$entityManager = $this->doctrine->getManager();
$sql="CALL procedure(parameter);";
$stmt = $entityManager->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I see it differently. I don't like it when answers are only meant to fill pages and don't get to the point. The questioner wanted an answer, this is an answer (which, by the way, I had to find myself, since all the other answers were also half novels again, but did not offer any solutions).