# How execute a stored procedure in silex with dbal (doctrine)?

Tags: php, ubuntu, doctrine, silex, dbal

I was looking for this information on the site http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html - but have not found anything. I tried to write in the style of PDO and a got syntax error, but the request was performed. Maybe someone knows what is the reason? Thanks

Mysql version 5.5
Php version 5.5
Ubuntu 13.04

EDIT:

Use this:

```
$query = $app['db']->prepare('CALL AddIncoming(?)');
$query->bindValue(1, $id_user);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705953/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-with-doctrine2-and-mysql

Comment: thanks, but i found another solution. i used yesterday EXEC statment (as in MSSQL), but in MYSQL for call stored procedure must use - CALL.