# Symfony2 + Stored procedure || How to fetch the result?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, stored-procedures, symfony-2.4

I am currently struggling with fetching results out of `nativquery` in Symfony 2.4.3. To be simple I'am currently building a JobQueue/MsgQueue System which will just add/remove jobs in the queue. The Procedure will fetch the first job, set it active and SHOULD return the whole result. Exactly there is the problem - I can't fetch anything.

I used this as my example: [How to execute Stored Procedures with Doctrine2 and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705953/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-with-doctrine2-and-mysql)

Here is the code I use in a `ConsoleCommand Class`:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    ## start
    $output->writeln('<comment>Starting JobQueue Ping process</comment>');

    // set doctrine
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
    $result = $em->createNativeQuery(
        'CALL JobQueueGetJob (' .
        ':jobTypeCode' .
        ')', $rsm
    );

    $result->setParameters(array('jobTypeCode' => 1));
    $result->execute();
    $em->flush();

    if ($input->getOption('verbose')) {
        $output->writeln(var_dump($result->getResult()));
    }
}
```

Here you go with the Procedure code and the result:
***Code***

```
PROCEDURE `JobQueueGetJob`(IN `jobType` TINYINT(2))
BEGIN
DECLARE jId int(11);
  SELECT `msgId` into jId FROM `jobqueue` WHERE `MsgTypeCode` = jobType AND `jState` = 'N' LIMIT 1;
  IF jId IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE `jobqueue` SET `jState` = 'A' WHERE `msgId` = jId;
    SELECT * FROM `jobqueue` WHERE `msgId` = jId;
  END IF;
END
```

**Result via phpMyAdmin**

```
Your SQL query has been executed successfully
0 rows affected by the last statement inside the procedure
SET @p0 =  '1';

CALL `JobQueueGetJob` (
@p0
);
```

As the text suggest it will be no result returned but the last statement inside the procedure which should be the Query itself's.

---

**SOLUTION (Not the best)**
Command:

```
// set doctrine
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager()->getConnection();

// prepare statement
$sth = $em->prepare("CALL JobQueueGetJob(1)");

// execute and fetch
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch();

// DEBUG
if ($input->getOption('verbose')) {
    $output->writeln(var_dump($result));
}
```

**Output:**

```
array(5) {
  'msgId' =>
  string(3) "122"
  'msgTypeCode' =>
  string(1) "1"
  'jobCode' =>
  string(22) "http://mail.google.com"
  'jstate' =>
  string(1) "A"
  'created_at' =>
  string(19) "2014-02-01 03:58:42"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
The following is the solution I finally found. It is not the best one as there is no Mapping anymore but in my case it is not necessary.
Further: I needed to change to the the getConnection to fetch the PDO_MySQL and further change to `prepare` and `fetch()` functions. The vardump show's now the appropriate result.

```
// set doctrine
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager()->getConnection();

// prepare statement
$sth = $em->prepare("CALL JobQueueGetJob(1)");

// execute and fetch
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch();

// DEBUG
if ($input->getOption('verbose')) {
    $output->writeln(var_dump($result));
}
```

**Output:**

```
array(5) {
  'msgId' =>
  string(3) "122"
  'msgTypeCode' =>
  string(1) "1"
  'jobCode' =>
  string(22) "http://mail.google.com"
  'jstate' =>
  string(1) "A"
  'created_at' =>
  string(19) "2014-02-01 03:58:42"
}
```