# Apigility + Doctrine2 QueryProvider - Can't use created function on query builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I'm using Apigility to create a rest application, where the back-end and front-end are pretty much independent applications.

Ok, on the Back-end I'm using `'zf-apigility-doctrine-query-provider'` to create queries depending on the parameters sent via url (i.e `localhost?instancia=10`), but I need to process information using a MS SQL database stored function, something like this:

```
function createQuery(ResourceEvent $event, $entityClass, $parameters){

    /* @var $queryBuilder \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder */
    $queryBuilder = parent::createQuery($event,$entityClass, $parameters);

    if (!empty($parameters['instancia'])) {

        $queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('chapa.instancia', 'dbo.isItSpecial(:instancia)'))
        ->setParameter('instancia', $parameters['instancia']);
    }

    return $queryBuilder;        
}
```

However it simply won't work, it won't accept the `'dbo.isItSpecial'` and seems like I can't access the `ServiceLocator`, nor the `EntityManager` or anything but the `Querybuilder`.

I thought about creating a native query to get the result and the using it on the main query but seems like I can't create it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute Stored Procedures with Doctrine2 and MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705953/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-with-doctrine2-and-mysql)

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705953/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-with-doctrine2-and-mysql). You'll find your answer there...

Comment: I`ve seen the solution on that link, it`s similar but I`m using the apigility query provider so I won`t be able to use native query (well, at least I don`t know how to do it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I've found some ways to do this.

The class that the method was, extends this class

> ZF\Apigility\Doctrine\Server\Query\Provider\DefaultOrm

That means I have access to the ObjectManager. The Documentation doesn't help much, but the ObjectManager is actually an EntityManager (ObjectManager is just the interface), to discover this I had to use the get_class PHP command.

With the entity manager I could have done what Wilt sugested, something like this:

```
        $sqlNativa = $this->getObjectManager()->createNativeQuery("Select dbo.isItSpecial(:codInstancia) as codEleicao", $rsm);
```

However, I created a service that execute this function (it will be used in many places), so I also made a factory that set this service to the query provider class, on the configuration file it's something like this.

```
    'zf-apigility-doctrine-query-provider' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'instanciaDefaultQuery' => 'Api\Instancia\instanciaQueryFactory',
    ),
),
```

And the factory looks like something like this (the service is executing the NativeQuery like the response from Wilt):

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Api\EleitoChapaOrgao\EleitoChapaOrgaoQuery;

class InstanciaQueryFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceManager){
        $instanciaService = $serviceManager->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Service\Instancia');

        $query = new InstanciaQuery($instanciaService);

        return $query;
    }
}
```

Finally just add the constructor to the QueryProvider and the service will be avaliable there:

```
class InstanciaQuery extends DefaultOrm
{    
    protected $instanciaService;

    public function __construct(Instancia $instanciaService)
    {
        $this->instanciaService = $instanciaService;
    }

    public function createQuery(ResourceEvent $event, $entityClass, $parameters)    
    { /* The rest of the code goes here*/
```

Answer (score 0):

*In what class is this method? Add some context to your question.*

You do `parent::createQuery` which suggests that you are in [a `DoctrineResource` instance](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-doctrine/blob/master/src/Server/Resource/DoctrineResource.php#L62). If this is true it means that both [the `ServiceLocator`](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-doctrine/blob/master/src/Server/Resource/DoctrineResource.php#L62) and [the `ObjectManager`](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-doctrine/blob/master/src/Server/Resource/DoctrineResource.php#L139) are simply available in the class.

You can read on doing native queries in Doctrine [here in the Documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html):

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

$query = $entityManager->createNativeQuery(
    'SELECT id, name, discr FROM users WHERE name = ?', 
    $rsm
);
$query->setParameter(1, 'romanb');
$users = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Oh thanks, turns out I've found some solutions to this. I'll post then soon to help others.

Comment: By the way, do you know how to I mark a question as solved?

Comment: @user3320407 you can accept one of the answers and that will close the question.